# ReslutSet closed error in wilfdlfy + hibernate stack

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I got a Hibernate project running in Wildfly jboss. When I run a highload test it throws this error randomly:

```
    2017-04-11 19:58:49,758 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-42) IJ031050: The result set is closed
    2017-04-11 19:58:49,758 ERROR [com.omnia.pie.ws.TransactionDataControllerImpl] (default task-42) Transaction save failed: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.transaction.hibernate.model.NonTlf]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1152)
        at com.omnia.pie.ws.TransactionDataControllerImpl.saveNonTlfTransaction(TransactionDataControllerImpl.java:323)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
        at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:137)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:169)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:145)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.transaction.hibernate.model.NonTlf]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2792)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3363)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.jp

a.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031050: The result set is closed
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkState(WrappedResultSet.java:6004)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.next(WrappedResultSet.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper.getGeneratedIdentity(IdentifierGeneratorHelper.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    ... 128 more
```

The code is:

```
    @Override
        public synchronized NonTlf saveNonTlfTransaction(NonTlf trandata) {
            getEntityManager().clear();

            try
            {
                TSN tsn =  null;

                    final String queryString = "select model from TSN model where model.vtmId= :propertyValue";
                    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
                    query.setParameter("propertyValue", trandata.getTerminalId());
                    //System.out.println(trandata.toString());


                    try {
                        tsn = (TSN) query.getSingleResult();

                    } catch(NoResultException e) {
                        log.error("Transaction save failed" , e);
                        tsn = new TSN();
                        tsn.setTsn(1);
                        tsn.setVtmId(trandata.getTerminalId());
                        getEntityManager().persist(tsn);
                    }
                    if(tsn.getTsn() == 9999)
                        tsn.setTsn(0);
                    tsn.setTsn(tsn.getTsn() + 1);
                    getEntityManager().merge(tsn);


                trandata.setTsn(String.format("%04d",tsn.getTsn()));

                    getEntityManager().persist(trandata);

                System.out.println("Transaction id: " + trandata.getId());

                return (trandata);
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                log.error("Transaction save failed" , e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return (null);
            }
        }
```

I suppose it's got to be something wrong with Wildfly and hibernate interaction, becouse I've never seen it on other enviroments. Had anyone experienced such issue?

**UPDATE**:
This is what getEntityManager does:

```
    public synchronized EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManager;
        }
```

Nothing special about it. And this is how entityManager is obtained:

```
    public static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
        @PersistenceContext
        public static EntityManager entityManager;
        private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TransactionDataControllerImpl.class.getName());

        static
        {
            if(entityManagerFactory == null)
                entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");

            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }
```

Comment: What does `getEntityManager()` do (show the code)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Updated.

Comment: Which line throws a ResultSet closed exception? The stack trace doesn't show any line in your code regarding this error.

Comment: Well, log doesn't show what line it is so I don't know, I thought maybe some1 already had experienced this

Comment: It seems that you're not using transactions. It would probably help if you explicitly start a transaction and end it with a call to commit. You can also set FlushModeType to COMMIT, which ensures that Hibernate doesn't call flush too often (this results in a more consistent behaviour)

Comment: I can tell you're using an EJB, and therefore transactions. Is it @Stateless? What is the purpose of all the synchronization?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this is ejb and it is stateless. This is a rest service which writes to the databse so it has to be in sync

Comment: The synchronization will not do what you think because each client of that EJB will get it's own instance of it.

Comment: Well...are there any ways to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this:

> java.sql.SQLException: IJ031050: The result set is closed

is a consequence of the entity manager being shared between threads.

I think you need to use the database to manage locking. If you modify your code a little to something like:

```
@Stateless
public class TransactionDataControllerImpl {

    private static Logger log = ...;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public NonTlf saveNonTlfTransaction(NonTlf trandata) {
        try
        {
            TSN tsn =  null;

            final String queryString = "select model from TSN model where model.vtmId= :propertyValue";
            TypedQuery<TSN> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, TSN.class);
            query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            query.setParameter("propertyValue", trandata.getTerminalId());
            //System.out.println(trandata.toString());

            try {
                tsn = query.getSingleResult();

            } catch(NoResultException e) {
                log.error("Transaction save failed" , e); // what does this mean?
                tsn = new TSN();
                tsn.setTsn(1);
                tsn.setVtmId(trandata.getTerminalId());
                entityManager.persist(tsn);
                entityManager.lock(tsn, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            }
            if(tsn.getTsn() == 9999)
                tsn.setTsn(0);
            tsn.setTsn(tsn.getTsn() + 1);
            tsn = entityManager.merge(tsn);

            trandata.setTsn(String.format("%04d",tsn.getTsn()));

            entityManager.persist(trandata);

            System.out.println("Transaction id: " + trandata.getId());

            return (trandata);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Transaction save failed" , e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return (null);
        }
    }

}
```

This should yield better behaviour. It will help if your entities each have an `@Version` annotated column.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it did the job. Thanks a lot!