# Submit form data with selected drop down

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to update form data when I update select drop down and click submit button. I tried to implement this:

Constructor:

```
export class Contract {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public enabled: boolean,
    public name: string,
    public merchant_id: number,    
    public gateway: string,
    public descriptor: string
  ) {}
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContractService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  search(filter: ContractFilter, page: number, size: number): Observable<PagedResult<Contract>> {
    let params = this.buildFilterParams(filter);
    let pagedFilter = HttpUtils.appendPageParams(params, page, size);

    return this.http.get<PagedResult<Contract>>(environment.api.urls.contracts.base, {params: pagedFilter});
  }

  private buildFilterParams(filter: ContractFilter): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (filter.name) {
      params = params.append('name', filter.name);
    }
    if (filter.id) {
      params = params.append('id', filter.id);
    }

    if (filter.from) {
      params = params.append('from', DateUtil.offsetDate(filter.from.toISOString()));
    }

    if (filter.to) {
      params = params.append('to', DateUtil.offsetDate(filter.to.toISOString()));
    }
    return params;
  }

  save(contract: Contract) {
    return this.http.post(environment.api.urls.contracts.base, contract);
  }

  persist(contract: Contract) {
    return this.http.post(environment.api.urls.contracts.persist(contract.id), contract);
  }

  get(contractId: string): Observable<Contract> {
    return this.http.get<Contract>(environment.api.urls.contracts.get(contractId));
  }

  export() {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.contracts.export,  { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract',
  templateUrl: './contract.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contract.component.scss']
})
export class ContractComponent implements OnInit {

  contract: Contract = new Contract(null, null, null, null, null);
  merchants: MerchantList[];

  edit = false;

  valueExists = false;

  constructor(private contractService: ContractService,
              private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        if (params['id']) {
          return this.contractService.get(params['id']);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if (value != null) {
        this.contract = value;
        this.edit = true;
      }
    });

    this.merchantService.getMerchantsList()
     .subscribe(value => {
        if (value != null) {
          this.merchants = value;
        }
    });
  }

  clear() {
    this.contract.name = null;
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.edit) {
      this.contractService.persist(this.contract).subscribe(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['panel', 'contracts', 'list']);
      })
    } else {
      this.contractService.save(this.contract).subscribe(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['panel', 'contracts', 'list']);
        },
        error => this.handleError(error.error));
    }
  }

  handleError(error: string) {
    if (error === 'TRANSACTION_EXISTS') {
      this.valueExists = true;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<h1 class="title">New Contract</h1>

<form class="grid-wrapper" #f="ngForm">
  <div *ngIf="edit" class="form-group id">
    <label for="id">Transaction ID</label>
    <input id="id" type="text" name="id" class="form-control" disabled [(ngModel)]="contract.id">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group name">
    <label for="name">Contract name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="contract.name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group type">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label for="type">Merchant</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" name="type" [(ngModel)]="contract.merchant_id" id="merchant_id" required>
      <option selected>Please Select...</option>
      <option [value]="merchant.id" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{ merchant.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.invalid" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Strings in input field is updated but I can't find why when I select different value from the drop down value it's not updated.

Can you give me some advice where I'm wrong?

Comment: The code you provided looks all fine for me. Have you tested the API's which are called in ContractService's save, persist, and get methods, without the integration with the UI? Do those work especially in terms of merchant_id?

Comment: in backend I get this error https://pastebin.com/35z1vzvx

Comment: this looks an error from data persistence. As per the situation you explained in your question, this might be an error that happens when updating the merchant_id to database. Leave the UI as it is and you should firstly solve the issue.

Comment: As the warning message after the error message says, your code has a problem related to some kind of lock. I'm not so sure about hibernate, but I think [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388544/reslutset-closed-error-in-wilfdlfy-hibernate-stack) could be related to your issue. I think `query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);` and `entityManager.lock(tsn, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);` are the point of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

reference to https://angular.io/guide/forms 
Each input element has a name property that is required by Angular forms to register the control with the form.

your problem is in HTML Template 
you must change name property from "type" to "merchant_id" same as your model .

```
<select class="custom-select" name="merchant_id" [(ngModel)]="contract.merchant_id" id="merchant_id" required>
  <option selected>Please Select...</option>
  <option [value]="merchant.id" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{ merchant.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

as a general,

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name="first" (change)="selected()">
   <option *ngFor="let o of options">
      {{o.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Typescript

```
selectedOption: string;
options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
]

selected(){
   console.log(this.selectedOption)
}
```

For your case try this,

HTML

```
<select class="custom-select" name="type" [(ngModel)]="contract.merchant_id" id="merchant_id" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" required>
      <option selected>Please Select...</option>
      <option [value]="merchant.id" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{ merchant.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Typescript

```
onChange(merchant) {
   console.log(merchant);
}
```

Comment: Ok but I don't see how this can fix the issue with the code.

Comment: no, probably because logic for SQL update is not implemented?

Comment: Can you add your data model?

Comment: Post is updated. Anything else that you would like to see?

Comment: I think [(ngModel)]="contract.merchant_id" should be [(ngModel)]="contract.id"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183363/discussion-between-dhanika-thathsara-munasinghe-and-peter-penzov).

Answer (score 0):

Lets keep it simple and make the changes in the `select box` as - Use `merchant` as a value instead of `merchant id`. It will update the entire `merchant` object and the rest of the `field` will be updated automatically.

### html

```
 <select class="custom-select" name="type" 
        [(ngModel)]="contract" 
        [compareWith]="compareFn"
         id="merchant_id" required>
      <option selected>Please Select...</option>
      <option [ngValue]="merchant" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{ merchant.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

### ts

```
compareFn(a, b) {
    if (!a || !b) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return a.merchant_id === b.merchant_id; //you can use other property also
    }
  }
```